# Storing input from main class into class method

Tags: java

I am trying to store input from one class into an array that is in a separate class method, but I'm not really sure how to do this.[This is the class that is accepting the input that I want to store into the class method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYAGH.png)
[This is the class my class method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QUIm.png)

Comment: This would be easier to read if you put the code in your question instead of screenshots.

Comment: Show us the code which you wrote

Comment: Also, your static method doesn't do anything.

Comment: What you're looking for are [getter and setter methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your array as a static variable rather than a local variable.

```
public class State
{
   private static String[] info = new String[5];


   public static void store(State state) {
      info[0] = ...
   }

   ...
}
```

Another better option is to create State as `Concrete` class rather than a `Static` class, but you should crawl before you walk :)